# git diff: what pager?

Tags: git, diff, pager

When I run `git diff` on some file, what pager is it using?  I ask because for every other command line tool I use with a pager in Linux, when I quit (by typing 'q'), the terminal reverts to what it was displaying before, with the only evidence that I ran s.t. being the command line itself.  For example:

```
> git help diff
>
```

Same with `man`, `less` itself, etc.  But when I run `git diff`, the entire diff remains on the screen, even if it was hundreds of lines long.  So if I want to look at the output of previous commands, I have to scroll way back.

This seems to be the behavior of `less -X`, which "Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the  terminal".

I've read the documentation for `git diff`, but nowhere do I see it say how to restore the terminal to the way it was before I ran the diff.  I can `export PAGER=/bin/less`, but this has no effect (it's maybe the default pager for `git diff`).

It may be that `git diff` is somehow passing a `-X` parameter to `less`.  But if so, I don't see anyway to turn that behavior off (the man page for `less` is silent about this).

Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167735/can-less-f-be-usefully-combined-with-termcap-initialization.  But that doesn't tell my why `git diff` behaves as if it is passing the `-X` parameter.  (FWIW, my terminal reports that it's xterm-256color.)

Comment: As far as what I have guessed from reading the code myself, git uses its own pager.

Comment: Pretty sure it uses GIT_PAGER, followed by PAGER

Comment: The relevant docs for this are in `man git`, not `git help diff`.  Specifically, the options `--paginate`, `--no-pager`, the configuration options `core.pager` and `pager.<cmd>`, and the environment variables `PAGER` and `GIT_PAGER`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see which pager Git is using, you can use `git var GIT_PAGER`.  To find out the order of options that Git consults, you can use run `git var --help`; the manual page lists the order of options.

Note that by default Git sets some options when invoking the pager by setting some environment variables.  The default compile-time behavior is to set `LESS=FRX` and `LV=-c`.  If you don't want these options, you can override them by setting the environment variable yourself, in which case your settings will override Git's defaults.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!  the FRX corresponds to the -F, -R and -X command line args for `less`; without the R, the output looks pretty weird, with escape codes for color (I guess there are args you can supply to git's diff to avoid outputting those).  But the -F and especially the -R args were the ones I needed to turn off: `export LESS=R` (in bash).

Comment: Argh (pun intended).  Tried to edit my comment, but too late; the -F and *-X* args were what I needed to turn OFF.